# Zend framework 2 : " Connect Error: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied"

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have been working on the [official tutorial for ZF2](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/database-and-models.html).
At the end of the page, to see what gives the result, I get this long error:

```
An error occurred
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
Additional information:
Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\RuntimeException
File:
D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection.php:243
Message:
Connect Error: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Stack trace:
#0 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo.php(211): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection->connect()
#1 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter.php(175): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo->createStatement(NULL)
#2 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Sql\Sql.php(103): Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter->createStatement()
#3 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(234): Zend\Db\Sql\Sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#4 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(210): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->executeSelect(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#5 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(197): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->selectWith(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#6 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\module\Album\src\Album\Model\AlbumTable.php(24): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->select()
#7 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\module\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php(18): Album\Model\AlbumTable->fetchAll()
#8 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(87): Album\Controller\AlbumController->indexAction()
#9 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(469): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#11 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(209): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#12 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController.php(108): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#13 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#14 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#15 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(469): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#16 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(209): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#17 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(298): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#18 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\public\index.php(12): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#19 {main}
Previous exceptions:
PDOException
File:
D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection.php:239
Message:
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Stack trace:
#0 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection.php(239): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=zf...', NULL, NULL, Array)
#1 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo.php(211): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection->connect()
#2 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter.php(175): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo->createStatement(NULL)
#3 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Sql\Sql.php(103): Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter->createStatement()
#4 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(234): Zend\Db\Sql\Sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#5 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(210): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->executeSelect(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#6 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(197): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->selectWith(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#7 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\module\Album\src\Album\Model\AlbumTable.php(24): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->select()
#8 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\module\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php(18): Album\Model\AlbumTable->fetchAll()
#9 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(87): Album\Controller\AlbumController->indexAction()
#10 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#11 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(469): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#12 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(209): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#13 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController.php(108): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#14 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#15 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#16 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(469): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#17 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(209): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#18 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(298): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#19 D:\softs\UwAmp\www\zf2-tutorial\ZendSkeletonApplication\public\index.php(12): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#20 {main}
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need put your credentials in a local config file

```
// config/autoload/local.php:
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'username' => 'YOUR USERNAME HERE',
        'password' => 'YOUR PASSWORD HERE',
    ),
);
```

Comment: That's was my first idea but everything is ok in that file!

Comment: Actually all is a local.php.dist file ( which was already here, i didn't create it ). No use to create another one simply named local.php?

Comment: Then seems you have a bug/typo with the service manager. Without look your PHP Code is impossible to know

Comment: Yes! you need copy to do a copy of dst file in a php file. Dst files are examples

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16654/discussion-between-arnaud-ad-and-maks3w)

Answer (score 0):

Thank  Maks3w, I got the same error because I didn't create `local.php` file to add the code. I thought that `local.php.dist` works well.
Everything's great after I have the `local.php` with the code

// config/autoload/local.php:

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'username' => 'YOUR USERNAME HERE',
        'password' => 'YOUR PASSWORD HERE',
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a comment in **`local.php.dist`** that helped me to fix it:

```
// Copy this file without the .dist extension at the end and populate values as needed.
```