# Zend Framework- SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'webadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, zend-framework, database-connection, putty

I want to authenticate user with my controller, in localhost (127.0.0.1) it's working correctly , but in another host name , above error has occurred.
this is my config pattern for connection to server (application.ini)

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
resources.db.adapter                            = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.params.dbname                      = aaa
resources.db.params.username                    = bbb
resources.db.params.password                    = ccc
resources.db.params.hostname                    = d.e.f.g
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter              = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to turn `resources.db.params.hostname` in `resources.db.params.host`

locally works because the default is localhost

[Zend Framework application.ini config](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html)

Comment: try to visit this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410343/zend-framework-2-connect-error-sqlstate28000-1045-access-denied)